# How to add command line option to include an additional make options from the command line

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a Makefile and make.options and I dont want to edit the Makefile. 
I want to run the gnu make with some command line options to include the make.options in the Makefile.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly -- and I'm not sure I do, it's highly unclear -- then you can do it this way:

```
make -f make.options -f Makefile
```